# How to fix `user must specify LSN` when using AWS DMS for Postgres RDS

Tags: amazon-web-services, rds, dms

I'm trying to migrate and synchronize a PostgreSQL database using AWS DMS and I'm getting the following error.

```
Last Error Task error notification received from subtask 0, thread 0 
[reptask/replicationtask.c:2673] [1020101] When working with Configured Slotname, user must 
specify LSN; Error executing source loop; Stream component failed at subtask 0, component 
st_0_D27UO7SI6SIKOSZ4V6RH4PPTZQ ; Stream component 'st_0_D27UO7SI6SIKOSZ4V6RH4PPTZQ' 
terminated [reptask/replicationtask.c:2680] [1020101] Stop Reason FATAL_ERROR Error Level FATAL
```

I already created a replication slot and configured its name in the source endpoint.

DMS Engine version: 3.1.4

Does anyone knows anything that could help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Luan -

I experienced the same issue - I was trying to replicate data from Postgres to an S3 bucket.I would check two things - your version of Postgres and the DMS version being used.
I downgraded my RDS postgres version to 9.6 and my DMS version to 2.4.5 to get replication working.

[image]
You can find more details here - 
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_Source.PostgreSQL.html

I wanted to try the newer versions of DMS (3.1.4 and 3.3.0[beta])  as it has parquet support but I have gotten the same errors you mentioned above.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

It appears AWS expects you to use the `pglogical` extension rather than `test_decoding`. You have to:

1. add `pglogical` to `shared_preload_libraries` in parameter options
2. reboot
3. `CREATE EXTENSION pglogical;`

On `dms 3.4.2` and `postgres 12.3` without the `slotName=` setting DMS created the slot for itself. **Also** make sure you exclude the `pglogical` schema from the migration task as it has unsupported data types.

P.S. When DMS hits resource limits it silently fails. After resolving the LSN errors, I continued to get failures of the type `Last Error Task 'psql2es' was suspended due to 6 successive unexpected failures Stop Reason FATAL_ERROR Error Level FATAL` without any errors in the logs. I resolved this issue using the **Advanced task settings > Full load tuning settings** and tuning the parameters *downward*.